# PHP to check the location the email is sent as well as if he e-mail has bounced

Tags: php, email

I wanted to code a PHP program where in I can check wether the sent email has bounced or not.The other thing which I need to check is that the location of the user from where he is accessing the email.Is it possible through PHP.Or is this possible through any other technology?

Answer (score 1):

You can check the origin of the IP used to connect to your service on for instance ipinfo.org.

Checking bounced messages is a little harder and my advice would be not to implement it yourself, but use a service to check it like [mandrill](http://mandrill.com/).
With mandrill you can sent emails through their servers and they handle bounces etc etc. Through their api's and webhooks you can get notified of any bounce or other event.